# Convert Oracles (dbstart/oratab) instructions from Linux to Windows

Tags: windows, linux, oracle

I have the following Linux directions I am trying to follow and am looking for the Windows equivalent.  Any help would be appreciated.

1. Edit $ORACLE_HOME_LISTENER/bin/dbstart and $ORACLE_HOME_LISTENER/bin/dbshut scripts.

   ```
   # Add/modify the following
   ORACLE_HOME_LISTENER=/apps/oracle/product/11.1.0
   ORATAB=/etc/oratab
   ```
2. Edit /etc/oratab and add a SID entry for each database that will be created on the local machine.

   ```
   # Add an entry for blah
   blah:/apps/oracle/product/11.1.0:Y
   ```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really is no Windows equivalent for the two items in your list. The listener and database instances are implemented as separate Windows services. Each database instance that you would have listed in the oratab file will have its own service. The startup flag in the oratab file is replaced by the Startup Type in the service properties. The environment variables are managed in the Windows registry and are set up when you create a database with the Database Configuration Assistant (DBCA). Check out the [Windows Installation Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/install.111/b32006/toc.htm).